# Use IFTTT to add file from RSS item's URL to Dropbox

Tags: rss, dropbox, if-this-then-that

I'm trying to setup a recipe to download a torrent file automatically to my Dropbox. Pretty much like [this one](https://ifttt.com/recipes/4171-grab-torrent-from-rss-feed-and-put-in-dropbox) but with another RSS source.

This recipe works fine if the `entryUrl` is a direct download link. But if the `entryUrl` is using redirection it only downloads a strange binary file. The extension is good but the added file is corrupted and can't be used.

Is anyone getting such a behaviour and knows a workaround?

Comment: The behavior you're seeing doesn't surprise me. I mean, the IFTTT http client can only be so intelligent. I wouldn't let it follow redirects, either. Who knows where they might lead? (Not to mention the potential for infinite loops.) I'm afraid I don't have a solution for you. You're going to need to find something else which can resolve redirects.

Comment: "Who knows where they might lead?" : Users know what they are doing, no?  ( ok, don't trust users I know... XD ) Infinite loop can be stoped by adding a limit to redirections number. It doesn't seem like a huge matter to me. Anyway I'm working on something that might help. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is what I've done :

(solution for developpers. Needs a php server.)

I've writen a PHP script that get the file through redirection (using cURL) and return it.
It's another kind of redirection, but it works well with **ifttt**.

```
<?PHP
    //get url parameter
    $url = $_GET['url'];



    // send the right headers
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="toDownload.torrent"');


    //then download the new file using curl to follow redirection :
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // Important 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);

    $st = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    exit;
?>
```

Then I've used [Yahoo pipes](https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to modify the torrent RSS feed so each link becomes :

http:// [my.server.url]/**thisscript.php**?url=**http:// the.redirect.url/324pfokT5**

it makes **ifttt** believe its not a redirection and download the good file ! :)